# How to return my LINQ query result as a particular object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

How to return my LINQ query result as a particular object

```
public CountryTable GetSelectedEventInfo(string SelectedEventID)
{
    return (CountryTable) this.context.Event.Where(
                   e => e.EventID.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(SelectedEventID)));
}
```

Here is my model

```
public class CountryTable
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Startdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string EventUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my db context

```
public DbSet<CountryTable> Event { get; set; }
```

Given below is what I am trying to do

```
public CountryTable GetSelectedEventInfo(string SelectedEventID)
{
    return (CountryTable) this.context.Event.Where(
                   e => e.EventID.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(SelectedEventID)));
}
```

I need my query  result to return object of type CountryTable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `SingleOrDefault` method:

```
public CountryTable GetSelectedEventInfo(string SelectedEventID)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedEventID);
    return this.context.Event.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EventID == id);
}
```

Notice that this method will return null if no matching record is found in your database.

Comment: If it's a unique id, I rather use SingleOrDefault, or would you suggest still using FirstOrDefault? I know the result is the same for a unique id, but I'm just curious for good practice.

Comment: use SingleOrDefault - the semantics state exactly you want one record queried and returned. First can query >1 and you are saying "I just want the first of the result"

Comment: Good points. I have updated my answer to use SingleOrDefault to ensure unique record.